# c++ maximum array size

Tags: c++, arrays

I would like to create three single column matrixes. These are int[663], int[2470] and double[2470]. Unfortunately, when I try to print all those matrixes, the C++ Visual Studio doesn't print the entire results. I think that it only prints a small part of the matrix. I wondered if the array reached the maximum length in c++ Visual Studio. Or is there any other cause?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    int IRP_Row,A_Row,CIndx_Row;

    inFile.open("Data_662v2.dat");
    inFile >> IRP_Row >> CIndx_Row >>A_Row;



    int *IRP=new int[IRP_Row];
    int *CIndx=new int[CIndx_Row];
    double *A=new double[A_Row];
        for (int a = 0; a < IRP_Row; a++)

         inFile >> IRP[a] ;


    for (int b = 0; b < CIndx_Row; b++)

            inFile >> CIndx[b] ;

    for (int c = 0; c < A_Row; c++)

            inFile >> A[c] ;

    //print the IRP matrix
        for (int a = 0; a < IRP_Row; a++)

         cout<< IRP[a]<<endl ;

    system("pause");
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: You're only printing `IRP`, and doing it twice.

Comment: No problems with such small arrays

Comment: @JonathanPotter Sorry I updated my code. But even IRP is not printed entirely.

Comment: Are you sure the maximum number of lines in your console isn't just smaller than the size of the array you're printing? Just a guess, because I've run into the same problem with that being the reason.

Comment: @jonhopkins OK. Sounds interesting. How can I find the maximum number of lines in my console? For microsoft c++

Comment: Just redirect the output to a file. Will be quicker anyway.

Comment: I'm sure there's a better way to do it, such as a setting somewhere, but I'm lazy so personally I would just write a quick program with nothing more than `for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) cout << i << endl;` and just scroll up to the top and subtract the first number (increasing the end condition if the top line is 1)

Comment: @jon there's no such limit. You have remembered wrongly.

Comment: It was probably Eclipse or cmd (haven't worked in Visual Studio in a while so I don't know if it has a built-in console now) that I experienced that in. As I said, it was just a guess.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Still not sure what happened...but the output file has the complete arrays. Thank you

Comment: Do you need more help?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No,thx a lot. Do you have an email...if you don't mind

Comment: We don't do email here. That benefits nobody else. I'm glad we answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

> I wondered if the array reached the maximum length in c++ Visual Studio.

No. There's no problem at all with your arrays which are in fact very small. The largest is the double array which is a mere 20KB. In other words, it is tiny.

Your code does indeed print the entire array that your program creates. Your code is just fine.

You will find that the problem is more prosaic than you imagine. Perhaps you are reading file incorrectly. What are the actual values of the array sizes at runtime? Perhaps the file format is not as you understand it to be.

The bottom line is that your program can handle arrays of this size (they are tiny), and your code successfully reads values, and prints all that it reads.

---

Your variable names seem badly chosen. This looks like CSC sparse storage. The first three values you read are array lengths, but you name them rows which makes not very much sense to me. And why are there three length values instead of two? Surely the column indices and the values arrays are the same length?

Comment: You are right. It is sparse matrix.After debugging, the code can print the first 100+ element in IRP matrix. But when I run step over, those result disappears... and some new elements are printed

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the numeric limit of `std::size_t` with [`std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits), but I highly doubt you are overflowing that, which such a small size.

Answer (score 0):

The limit to array size depends on the architecture you are compiling for, the operating system, and the available RAM on the PC. In general, you shouldn't allocate more memory than is available. In 32 bit Windows, the maximum amount of memory that can be used by a single process is normally 2GB. In 64 bit systems it's a lot more.

An integer requires 4 bytes on a 32 bit architecture. So the maximum array size that you can use for an integer array on 32 bit Windows is about 500 million, minus the space that's taken up by the rest of your program. There are many other systems and configurations where that number will be a lot higher.

Comment: Contiguity constraint means limits are much lower

Comment: Not sure about that. I haven't had problems memory mapping 1 GB files in 32 bit Windows.

Comment: Clearly a single block of memory must be contiguous, and a process always has some of its address space taken up by other modules. You might allocate a single block of 1GB, but you'll not get very close to 2GB.